# Changing the attribute of each element in a v-for array

Tags: javascript, css, events, vue.js

I am attempting to figure things out with Vue way of writing javascript.

Considering this scenario:

at .vue `template`

```
 <button  v-on:click="biggerFont()" class="btn btn-s btn-default" type="button" name="button">A</button>

   <div v-for="(tweet, index) in tweets">
      <div class="each_tweet">
        <textarea v-on:keyup="typing(index)"
                  v-model="tweet.content"
                  placeholder="What's happening now">{{ tweet.content }}</textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
```

at .vue `<script>`

```
export default {
  methods: {
    biggerFont:  function() {

       //can I somehow use this.tweets.style.fontSize to influence all the fontSize? 
       document.getElementsByClassName("each_tweet").style.fontSize = "xx-large"  
    }
 }
}
```

My question is:

1. how do I go about changing the font-size of each value of the textarea in `tweets`? Is there a default Vue way of influencing these fontSize?

I tried and failed using `document.getElementsByClassName.style.fontSize` and it does not seems to be the Vue way. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Vue way of doing this is using class and style bindings. For example:

`<textarea v-bind:class="{ big: enlarge}">{{item}}</textarea>`

https://jsfiddle.net/e064m859/

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` method returns a `nodeList` so you have to access a `DOM` element using its index.

```
export default {
  methods: {
     biggerFont:  function() {
          var tweets=document.getElementsByClassName("each_tweet");
          for(var i=0;i<tweets.length;i++){
              tweets[i].style.fontSize = "xx-large";
          }  
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, as more tweets are added, the fontSize affects only the fontSize of existing textarea. Do you have a solution which will affect current and future textarea?

Comment: One way is that I could also set a global data value and assign it each time i create a new textarea.

Comment: Yes, this could be a solution,

Comment: Do you want to change style only when click the button ?

Comment: Yes. I think clicking the "bigger font" button should affect all textarea and future textareas. (Since there's a v-for of tweets)